# How to debug into system.servicemodel classes?

Tags: wcf, debugging

How can i debug system.sevicemodel classes in my application?

Comment: what classes do you want to debug??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It sounds like your interested in debugging the .NET framework code itself?  If so, Microsoft has released source code to the public for much of the .NET framework.

However, to the best of my knowledge this **does not** include additions such WF, WPF and WCF (system.servicemodel), so you may be out of luck just yet.  I could be wrong though, so it might worthwhile to review the following articles and see about setting up for debugging into .NET source to verify that these additions have not been added in the last year or so.

Check out ScottGu's [announcement on releasing .NET source code](http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/archive/2008/01/16/net-framework-library-source-code-now-available.aspx) to the public and how to get started.  Be sure to follow some of the links in the announcement, specifically Shawn Burkes [Configuring Visual Studio to Debug .NET Framework Source Code](http://blogs.msdn.com/sburke/archive/2008/01/16/configuring-visual-studio-to-debug-net-framework-source-code.aspx).

If you decide to head down this road, it might be worthwhile to read these two posts by John Robbins, [Additional .NET Framework Source Code Debugging Tricks](http://www.wintellect.com/cs/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2008/01/17/additional-net-framework-source-code-debugging-tricks.aspx) and an overview of the [.NET Mass Downloader Utility](http://www.wintellect.com/CS/blogs/jrobbins/archive/2008/02/06/download-all-the-net-reference-source-code-at-once-with-net-mass-downloader.aspx).

If you had a more specific question in mind, please let us know!

Good Luck!
Z